# How would you extract the cid value from this?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am working on a script to take a user defined term, and then print the card information for that card, but I can't work out how to extract the 'cid' to then recreate the next url i need. My current code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def search_card1(p_message):
    # create URL with search term
    url = f"https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=1&sess=1&rp=10&mode=&sort=1&keyword={p_message}&stype=1&ctype=&othercon=2&starfr=&starto=&pscalefr=&pscaleto=&linkmarkerfr=&linkmarkerto=&link_m=2&atkfr=&atkto=&deffr=&defto="
    print(url)
    # send request and get response
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    # parse HTML content using BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    
    # find all card links on the page
    card_links = soup.find_all('div', class_='t_row c_normal')
    print (card_links[0])
    print("The variable, card_links is of type:", type(card_links))
    if not card_links:
        return "No results found."
    
    # extract the first card link and go to its details page
    defCard = 'https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=2&cid='
    cid = card_links[0]['cid']
    card_url = defCard + cid
    print(card_url)
    response = requests.get(card_url)
    
    # parse HTML content of the card details page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    
    # extract the card name and age
    card_name = soup.find('card_name', class_='card_status_title').text.strip()
    card_age = soup.find('div', class_='box_card_info').find_all('span')[1].text.strip()
    
    # return the card name and age as a string
    return f"Card Name: {card_name}\nAge: {card_age}"

p_message = 'Dark+Magician'
card_data = search_card1(p_message)
print(card_data)
```

The print function prints out the CID near the bottom, but I can't then access it to save it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your elements more specific, the url is stored in a hidden `<input>` with `class` named `link_value`:

```
# find all card links on the page
card_links = ['https://www.db.yugioh-card.com'+e.get('value') for e in soup.select('.link_value')]
print (card_links)
```

> KeyError: [attr] - Caused by accessing tag['attr'] when the tag in
> question doesn’t define the attr attribute. The most common errors are
> KeyError: 'href' and KeyError: 'class'. Use tag.get('attr') if you’re
> not sure attr is defined, just as you would with a Python dictionary.

##### Output

```
['https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=2&cid=4041', 'https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=2&cid=4766', 'https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=2&cid=11151', 'https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=2&cid=5756', 'https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=2&cid=5880', 'https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=2&cid=13357', 'https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=2&cid=10322', 'https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=2&cid=12416', 'https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=2&cid=5649', 'https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action?ope=2&cid=14905']
```